# Cant see <h1> in the middle of DIVS

Tags: html, css

Any idea why I can't see H1?

```
<div id="getTheProducts" style="clear: both; margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px; border: 1px solid #DDD;background-color: #f8f8f8; width: 857px; height: 50px; text-align: left;">
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="getProductsSlide" style="width: 850px; overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
<div class="getProducts_Cover" style="width:56950px; position: absolute; height:50px;">
<div class="getProducts_Page" style="display: block; width: 850px; float: left; height: 50px; color: #000;">
<h1>2012 - January Newsletter</h1></div>
</div></div></div></div>
```

Chrome shows it as there, It outlines it, it even tells me the width/height, but I cant actually see the text.  I put it into a single HTML page, I still cant see it.  I must be missing a css rule somewhere.

Comment: remove overflow hidden in your css

Comment: or set a `height` to it ("getProductsSlide" element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi you can remove `overflow:hidden;`

```
<div id="getTheProducts" style="clear: both; margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px; border: 1px solid #DDD;background-color: #f8f8f8; width: 857px; height: 50px; text-align: left;">
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="getProductsSlide" style="width: 850px; position: relative;"> // **here remove overflow hidden**
<div class="getProducts_Cover" style="width:56950px; position: absolute; height:50px;">
<div class="getProducts_Page" style="display: block; width: 850px; float: left; height: 50px; color: #000;">
<h1>2012 - January Newsletter</h1></div>
</div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Yeah i can't really do that because its all tied into a Jquery thing.  I moved the overflow:hidden though an it seems to work properly now.  But thank you for telling me what the problem was! :)

Answer (score 0):

What disables the display of the headline is the *position: absolute;* in

```
<div class="getProducts_Cover" style="width:56950px; position: absolute; height:50px;">
```

If possible change that to

```
<div class="getProducts_Cover" style="width:56950px; position: relative; height:50px;">
```